# How to extract stream of images from video file using ffmpeg

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I want to extract stream of images from a video file using ffmpeg.

I know I can extract them straight to the hard drive using these arguments:

-i - -qscale 1 h:\out\img-%05d.jpg

But i would like to extract directly to a stream.

This is my code so far:

```
private void ExtractImagesFromVideo(byte[] data,string _args)
    {
        try
        {
            serverBuild = new Process();
            serverBuild.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            serverBuild.StartInfo.Arguments = _args;
            serverBuild.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\ffmpeg.exe";
            serverBuild.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            serverBuild.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            serverBuild.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            serverBuild.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            serverBuild.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            serverBuild.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = false;
            serverBuild.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            serverBuild.Start();

            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(serverBuild.StandardInput.BaseStream))
            {
                bw.Write(data);
            }

            mStandardOutput = serverBuild.StandardOutput.BaseStream;
            mStandardOutput.BeginRead(mReadBuffer, 0, mReadBuffer.Length, StandardOutputReadCallback, null);
            serverBuild.WaitForExit();
            byte[] _data = mStandardOutputMs.ToArray();
            mStandardOutput.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception _ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {               
            serverBuild.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

and I call like like this:

```
     string _argsOut = @"-i pipe:0 -qscale 1 -f mjpeg pipe:1 ";
     ExtractImagesFromVideo(data, _argsOut);
```

and it hangs on this line:

```
bw.Write(data);
```

thanks

Answer (score -1):

The other day I accidentally did this while trying to extract a single image out of a video with FFMPEG.

Here is the command line you want: "-i input.flv -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1 out%d.png"

Input.flv is the source, fps=fps=1 will make an image every second of the video, and out%d.png will be the outputted file. The "%d" is need between the file name and the file extension as this will create a pattern like so: out1.png, out2.png, out3.png and so on.

Comment: Hi, sorry. That did not actually give me an array of jpegs.  It just gave me the video file in bytes?

Comment: Oh dear sorry about that. That should of worked :s my bad! Try this "-i inputfile.avi  -r  1  -t  4  image-%d.jpeg". -r 1 means one frame per second, and -t 4 means for a duration of 4 seconds.
I have a list of loads of FFMPEG command lines stored in a text document and this is another one I have for extracting frames. That should work if not I have a few options left :p

Comment: hi, I really appreciate your time and help in this but what I am actually looking for is getting the jpegs in a stream derived from a the stdout pipe in the process class. All this does is write the jpegs/images to the hard drive which is not what I want.